# ERRO em linha do formulario

Tags: php, mysql, sintaxe

No navegador da o seguinte erro, já tentei de tudo se puderem ajudar

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or
>   T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN in

```
<?php
echo "NOVO MOTORISTA";
include('conexao.php');
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    foreach($_POST AS $key=>$value){$_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);}
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'motoristas'('cod_mot', 'nome', 'endereco', 'cidade','cod_veiculo')
    VALUES('{$_POST['cod_mot']}', '{$_POST['nome']}, '{$_POST['endereco']}, '{$_POST['cidade']}, '{$_POST['cod_veiculo']}')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "registro adicionado.<br/>";
    echo "<a href='listar_m.php'>Voltar à listagem</a>;
}
?>
<html>
<form action= method='POST'>
<p><b>Cod Mot:</b><br/><input type='text' name='cod_mot'/>
<p><b>Nome:</b><br/><input name='nome' type='text' size= '50'/>
<p><b>Endereco:</b><br/><input name='endereco' type='text' size='50'/>
<p><b>Cidade:</b><br/><input name='cidade' type='text' size='50'/>
<p><b>Cod Veiculo:</b><br/><input type='text' name='cod_veiculo'/>
<p><input type='submit' value='Salvar'/><input type='hidden' value='1' name='submitted'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Edite sua postagem e poste seu código, por favor!

Comment: A mensagem de erro não parece estar completa, e falta código referente ao erro, como a variável `$end` mencionada no erro

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro pode ocorrer quando uma sequência foi aberta e não foi fechada (ex.: chaves, colchetes, aspas).

Veja no seu código na linha abaixo que está faltando 3 aspas simples na inserção dos valores:

```
'{$_POST['nome']}, '{$_POST['endereco']}, '{$_POST['cidade']},
```

Quando o correto seria:

```
             FALTANDO                FALTANDO               FALTANDO
                 ↓                       ↓                     ↓
'{$_POST['nome']}', '{$_POST['endereco']}', '{$_POST['cidade']}',
```

E faltando uma aspas dupla nesta linha:

```
                                               FALTANDO
                                                  ↓
echo "<a href='listar_m.php'>Voltar à listagem</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

O ultimo `echo "<a href='listar_m.php'>Voltar à listagem</a>;` não tem as aspas duplas fechando, complementando, o comando de insert precisa ter as aspas ' antes e depois do `{$_POST['valor'}`